# Newsletter2Go - Form does not work after filling it with javascript?

Tags: javascript, newsletter, newsletter2go

I try to automatically fill the newsletter2go form with customer data. The form is getting created dynamically with a javascript code which I got from the newsletter2go backend.

But I found out, that the form does not work anymore if I fill it by using javascript!? It works perfectly fine if I fill it manually by hand.

I executed this code from the developer console:

```
    var inputEmail = document.getElementsByClassName("newsletterInput")[0],
        inputVorname = document.getElementsByClassName("newsletterInput")[1],
        inputNachname = document.getElementsByClassName("newsletterInput")[2],
        selectAnrede = document.getElementsByClassName("newsletterSelect")[0];

    if (inputEmail.value == "") {
        inputEmail.value = 'foo@bar.de';
    }

    if (selectAnrede.value == "") {
        selectAnrede.value = 'm';
    }

    if (inputVorname.value == "") {
        inputVorname.value = 'Edward';
    }
    if (inputNachname.value == "") {
        inputNachname.value = 'Black';
    }
```

The form is getting filled but if I submit then I get to see **Sorry, an error has occurred. Please check your data.**

Request Payload at this point:
[image]

Why does it fail?

---

If the browser auto-fills the form, then it works btw.

Comment: Have you tried with your data in double quote "data", instead of single quote 'data'?

Comment: I tried it, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way the form works is that it only gets updated `onchange`. That means if you trigger that manually, your code will work.

Since this seems a bit like a workaround, a cleaner solution would be to implement it similar to a sample form implementation found on the [Newsletter2Go homepage](https://www.newsletter2go.de/docs/html-formular-nl2go.html).
The corresponding help article [can be found here](https://hilfe.newsletter2go.com/automation/formulare/wie-kann-ich-ein-eigenes-html-als-formular-verwenden.html) (only available in German atm).

BTW, Newsletter2Go [offers a recipient profile link](https://hilfe.newsletter2go.com/empfanger-verwalten/import/wie-gebe-ich-den-kunden-die-moglichkeit-ihr-profil-zu-bearbeiten.html) that automatically fills the form with customer data. Maybe you can just use that instead.